# Pygame дергаются спрайты во время передвижения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Красный квадрат - персонаж, белое поле - пол, серое поле - стены.

На гифке не очень хорошо видно, но все движется с одинаковой скоростью. Но иногда движение либо приостанавливается на 1 кадр, либо происходит движение как за 2 кадра (видео - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/pG9y13Szq3pyRg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если оставить только необходимый минимум (а именно движение плиток): в функции обновления экрана (метод update класса Base) убрать проверку коллизий и отрисовку персонажа, а в функции обновления плиток (метод update класса Floor) вместо проверки нажатия клавиш постоянно прибавлять к координате x или y скорость (4px), то движение все так же останется дерганым.

```
def update(self): # class: Base
        while True:
            self.screen.fill((20,20,20))
            self.checkEvents()
            self.stageRects.update(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.FPS)

def update(self, screen): # class: Floor
        self.rect.x -= 4

        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

В конце, при соприкосновении со стеной, персонаж начинает дергаться - это тоже 1 из проблем на которую я хотел бы найти решение. Коллизия обрабатывается в методе класса Floor, 1 аргументом которого (после ссылки на экземпляр класса) является direction - список текущего направления движения. Я решил не наследовать класс с персонажем от класса pygame.Sprite, т. к. невозможно проверить коллизию конкретной стороны спрайта.

Например `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player.rect.topleft, group)` будет ошибка, ведь rect.**topleft** это не Rect, а пара значений x,y **int**, нельзя сравнивать Rect и int. По этому в функции обновления экрана проверяется коллизия 4 сторон персонажа как 4 разных квадрата. Я хотел бы узнать, возможно ли через spritecollide проверить разные стороны Rect.

```
for stage in self.stageRects:
        self.player.rectLeft.colliderect(stage)
        self.player.rectRight.colliderect(stage)
        self.player.rectTop.colliderect(stage)
        self.player.rectBottom.colliderect(stage)
```

Код максимально упрощен и несколько файлов объединены в 1:

```
import pygame, sys, json

class Base:
    def __init__(self, screen, fps, clock):
        self.screen = screen
        self.FPS = fps
        self.clock = clock
        self.topWall = pygame.Surface((64,64)); self.topWall.fill("grey")
        self.floor = pygame.Surface((64,64)); self.floor.fill("white")
        self.player = Player()

        self.loadStage() # Load level
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            self.screen.fill((20,20,20))
            self.checkEvents()
            hitList = []
            hitL = []; hitR = []; hitTop = []; hitBtm = []
            for stage in self.stageRects:
                hitL.append(self.player.rectLeft.colliderect(stage))
                hitR.append(self.player.rectRight.colliderect(stage))
                hitTop.append(self.player.rectTop.colliderect(stage))
                hitBtm.append(self.player.rectBottom.colliderect(stage))
            hitList.extend([hitL, hitR, hitTop, hitBtm])
            self.stageRects.update(self.player.get_direction(), self.screen, hitList)
            self.player.update(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.FPS)

    def loadStage(self):
        self.stageRects = pygame.sprite.Group()  # Floor, walls and more
        file = open('stage1.json')
        stage = json.load(file)

        iteration = -1
        for index in stage:
            iteration += 1

            if index == 0:
                continue
            elif index == 1:
                Floor(self.floor, ((iteration % 32) * 64, (iteration // 32) * 64, 64, 64), self.stageRects) # 64 - block size (64x64px) 
            elif index == 2:
                Floor(self.topWall, ((iteration % 32) * 64, (iteration // 32) * 64, 64, 64), self.stageRects) 

    def checkEvents(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

class Floor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, rect, group):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = img
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.group = group
        self.add(group)

    def update(self, direction, screen, hitList): # Move Floor
        if direction[0]: # Left
            if 1 not in hitList[0]: # 1 - True
                self.rect.x -= direction[4] # direction[4] - speed
            else:
                self.rect.x += direction[4] 
        elif direction[1]: # Right
            if 1 not in hitList[1]:
                self.rect.x += direction[4]
            else: 
                self.rect.x -= direction[4]

        if direction[2]: # Up
            if 1 not in hitList[2]:
                self.rect.y -= direction[4]
            else:
                self.rect.y += direction[4]
        elif direction[3]: # Down
            if 1 not in hitList[3]:
                self.rect.y += direction[4]
            else:
                self.rect.y -= direction[4]

        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((64,64))
        self.image.fill("red")

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 960 + 32; self.rect.y = 540 - 32 # Center screen
        self.rectLeft = pygame.Rect(self.rect.x - 64, self.rect.y, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)
        self.rectRight = pygame.Rect(self.rect.x + 64, self.rect.y, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)
        self.rectTop = pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y - 64, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)
        self.rectBottom = pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + 64, self.rect.w, self.rect.h)
        self.speed = 4

    def get_direction(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            ML = True
            MR = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            MR = True
            ML = False
        else:
            MR = False; ML = False # MR - Moving Right, ML - Moving Left
        
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            MU = True
            MD = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            MD = True
            MU = False
        else:
            MU = False; MD = False # MU - Moving Up, MD - Moving Down

        return [ML, MR, MU, MD, self.speed]

    def update(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1920, 1080])
        FPS = 60
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        
        Base(screen, FPS, clock)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

В конструкторе класса Base загружается уровень из json файла, 0 - пустота, 1 - пол, 2 - стена

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Экземпляры класса Floor добавляются в группу stageRects - это пол.

Класс Player - персонаж

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы было плавненько, включите `vsync`.
Для этого уберите ограничение по FPS в `self.clock.tick()`.
И режим, выставьте, например, так:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1920, 1080], pygame.SCALED | pygame.FULLSCREEN, vsync=1)
```

Ну, а дёрганье в конце вы сами зачем-то реализовали. Зачем-то, то плюс direction, то минус direction.
Ведь всё проще:

```
class Floor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #...
    def update(self, direction, screen, hitList): # Move Floor
        if direction[0] and any(hitList[0]): # Left      1 - True
                self.rect.x += direction[4]  # direction[4] - speed
        if direction[1] and any(hitList[1]): # Right
                self.rect.x -= direction[4]
        if direction[2] and any(hitList[2]): # Up
                self.rect.y += direction[4]
        if direction[3] and any(hitList[3]): # Down
                self.rect.y -= direction[4]

        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

И `get_direction()` тоже делается проще:

```
class Player():
    #...
    def get_direction(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        ML = keys[pygame.K_a] # MR - Moving Right
        MR = keys[pygame.K_d] # ML - Moving Left
        MD = keys[pygame.K_w] # MU - Moving Up
        MU = keys[pygame.K_s] # MD - Moving Down

        return [ML, MR, MU, MD, self.speed]
```

Тогда *(по совокупности работы этих двух функций)* одновременное нажатие кнопок отвечающих за противоположное движение будет это движение останавливать (что логично).